# Conditionally navigate from apex:actionFunction

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

We have an `apex:actionFunction` like so:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="communityLogin" action="{!login}">
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!username}" id="usernameHidden"/>
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!password}" id="passwordHidden"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

This calls a controller function:

```
public PageReference login(){
    String redirectPage = '/login-success';
    PageReference loginPage = Site.login(username, password, redirectPage); 
    if(loginPage != null){
        return loginPage;
    }
    else{
        PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
        //pageRef.getParameters().put('invalidLogin', 'true');
        pageRef.setRedirect(false);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

Javascript code (inside Angular component, called by button click):

```
login(){
if(this.loginForm.valid){
  this.loggingIn = true; // to show a spinner
  let usernameElem:any = document.getElementById(window.usernameHiddenId);
  let passwordElem:any = document.getElementById(window.passwordHiddenId);
  if(usernameElem && passwordElem){
    usernameElem.value = this.username.value;
    passwordElem.value = this.password.value;
    window.communityLogin();
  }
}
```

}

What we're trying to do here is to keep the user on the same page if they couldn't log in. (The javascript client app then will notify the user in a polite manner).
However, this doesn't work.
It always navigates to the Community's designated index page.
I understand from the docs that setting `pageRef.setRedirect(false)` should prevent the `apex:actionFunction` from navigating.
But that doesn't happen. It always navigates away from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apex:actionFunction does not have a reRender attribute, so it is reloading the page. This appears like you're navigating because Angular has to reinitialize, so it appears as if you've navigated to another page, but it's simply reloading. Adding a reRender attribute to the apex:actionFunction will prevent this from happening.

Comment: Nope. It prevents default behavior, but doesn't stop the navigation. No reason why it should. That's a different form from the one in the VF page. That form (VF) has no button.

Comment: @AvailableName Hmm. The only other thing that comes to mind is that your apex:actionFunction doesn't have a reRender attribute, but that should only cause it to reload the current page, not navigate elsewhere.

Comment: That was it. It was reloading the page. But we're using the Angular router to navigate _within the same VF page_. So reloading the same page just looked like it was navigating away. I feel like such a dunce.

Comment: @AvailableName No worries, we've all been there.

Comment: You wanna change your answer?

Comment: @AvailableName Sure thing. 